# How to Exit Installer on Button Click Without Confirmation During Modify Process?

Tags: installation, advanced-installer

I'm working with Advanced Installer to create a setup package for my application. During the modification process, I've introduced a scenario where users can update their data through a custom UI. In this UI, there's an "Exit" button that, when clicked, should immediately close the installer without prompting any confirmation dialogs and effectively abort the installation process.

My current implementation involves adding a "Terminate Process" custom action, specifying "MyInstaller.exe" as the parameter. This custom action is triggered by the "Exit" button at the end of the modify dialog. While this method works, it forcibly terminates the installer process, which doesn't seem like the most graceful way to exit.

I'm seeking a more elegant solution that allows the installer to close immediately upon the button click, without navigating to the exit page or displaying any confirmation prompts to the user. Is there a better approach to achieve this behavior in Advanced Installer?

**Note**: The requirement is to ensure that the installer exits directly without any further user interaction or displaying the exit page.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution solution would be to trigger the "Close the current dialog -> Exit" event from your UI Exit button.

This way the installation process will be naturally stopped by the Windows Installer service.

Also, in case you do not want to display the UserExit dialog you should simply make sure the AiSkipUserExit property is set to 1. Something like below:

[image]